# Passive redirect to WS-Fedration Site on click of Sign In page in MVC application

Tags: single-sign-on, thinktecture-ident-server, thinktecture-ident-model, thinktecture

I have an application which is using thinktecture to do single sign on. I have configure the passive redirect in web.config file.

I want my home page to be loaded first and then on click of login/sign in button need to do passive redirect, authenticate and redirect to my home page.

Need help to achive it

Comment: Perhaps start with what you've tried?

Comment: On Click of my Login it should passive redirect and redirect back to my Home page of the application with authorized user